# asp.net charts: Legend overlapping with X-axis

Tags: charts, legend, legend-properties

I am creating a Chart (DataVisualization.Charting.Chart) programmatically, which is a Stacked Bar chart.

I am also adding Legend entries programmatically to it. I want to show the Legend at the bottom of the chart.

But, while doing so, the Legend overlapps with the X-axis of the chart.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Private Function GetLegend(ByVal legendName As String, ByVal s As Single) As     System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend

 Dim objLegend As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend = New System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend()

 objLegend.Name = legendName
 objLegend.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", s)
 objLegend.IsDockedInsideChartArea = False
 objLegend.Docking = Docking.Bottom
 Return objLegend
End Function
```

Below statement adds that Legend to the chart

```
_msChart.Legends.Add(GetLegend("SomeValue1", 10.0F))
```

Any idea, what is missing? I want to show the legend at the bottom only, but it should not overlapp with the X-axis.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today. Try adding:

```
objLegend.Position.Auto = true
objLegend.DockedToChartArea = "yourChartAreaName"
```

That did not help me but I found on the net that this might be helpful (and clean solution).

What actually worked for me was moving chart area to make space for legend so it no longer overlaps. My legend was on top so this code worked for me:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].Position.Y = 15
```

You can try resizing it instead, forcing it to be for example 20 pixels shorter than `chart.Size`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had an overlapping legend/chart area problem as well but none of the other suggestions here seemed to make any difference. I think the problem stems from legend text wrapping to two lines and the sizing algorithms not taking account of this.

The ideas here got me thinking more clearly about the problem though, and I was able control the size and position of the chart area using the following.

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(15, 5, 90, 75);
```

There's not much intellisense on those parameters, but as well as I could deduce, the parameters are all percentages of the total chart area (I initially thought they might be pixel values and got some *very* odd results). So what I've written above would set the plot area to start at 15% in from the left edge of the chart image and 5% down from the top, and have a width of 90% and a height of 75%.